# I can't understand why my div won't act resizable?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, resizable

Can someone please look at this code and explain why this div is not resizable. I have stripped the code down to bare bones, looking for the error. There must be something obvious that I'm unaware of.

Desired Functionality: 
The `<div>` needs to be resizable. It needs to be something a user can drag with a mouse to increase the width and height of the object.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0">
</head>

<body>

<style>
            .Work{
                position: relative;
                width: 100%;
                height: 10%;
                top: calc(12.5% + 1vh);
            }

            .object{
                position: absolute;
                height: 3.7vh;
                width: 12.75625vh;
                border: 3px solid #4286f41a;
                box-sizing: border-box;
                margin-left: 1.5vh;
                flex-shrink: 0;
            }
</style>



    <div class="Work">
        <div class="object"></div>
    </div>



      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>>

      <script>
          $(document).ready(function(){
            $(function(){
                $(".object").resizable();
                 });
         });
      </script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your example has some syntax errors. I would address those first. You also have various versions of jQuery included.

Comment: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">` you're forgetting the stylesheet of jqueryUI

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to make this work, **you need to include `jquery-ui.css` as well**. Also, **there is no need to include two different versions of jQuery at the same time**, so I will just include `v3.5.1`.

So your final code should be something like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
</head>

<body>

  <style>
    .Work {
      position: relative;
      width: 100%;
      height: 10%;
      top: calc(12.5% + 1vh);
    }
    
    .object {
      position: absolute;
      height: 3.7vh;
      width: 12.75625vh;
      border: 3px solid #4286f41a;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      margin-left: 1.5vh;
      flex-shrink: 0;
    }
  </style>



  <div class="Work">
    <div class="object"></div>
  </div>



  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $(function() {
        $(".object").resizable();
      });
    });
  </script>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: There's something strange both of my browsers don't want to allow that functionality. I copied and pasted it into the WS3Schools editor, and it ran perfectly. I can't make sense of that.

Comment: I have no idea, but thanks. I now know, beyond the syntax errors, that the issue lies somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following code.

```js
$(function() {
  $(".object").resizable();
});
```

```css
.Work {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10%;
  top: calc(12.5% + 1vh);
}

.object {
  position: absolute;
  height: 3.7vh;
  width: 12.75625vh;
  border: 3px solid #4286f41a;
  background-color: #ccc;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-left: 1.5vh;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="Work">
  <div class="object">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

You had a number of syntax errors and were missing the jQuery UI CSS. Once corrected, the code works as expected.